# DataGridView show row on bottom

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I show the next selected row **on top of grid** using `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property like this:

```
int currentIndex = dgvMain.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
int[] highlightedArray = HighlightedRows.ToArray();
highlightedArray = highlightedArray.OrderBy(h => h).ToArray();
var next = highlightedArray.FirstOrDefault(r => r > currentIndex);
dgvMain.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = next;
```

but how can I show the next selected row **on bottom of grid**? I searched for a property but didn't find anything.

---

If there was a method or property which could tell me how many rows I see at a time, it would be helpful, something like:

```
dgvMain.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = next + dgvMain.RowsPerView;
```

lets say I see 10 rows per view, and I want to show 36th row on bottom of my grid, in this situation showing the 27th row (36 - 9) on top would do the trick, because there are 9  other rows (10 - upper row) below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `DataGridView.DisplayedRowCount()`

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.displayedrowcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details

Comment: Although I can not yet show a full row on bottom and a partial row on top (as experienced users say it is very hard to implement), DisplayedRowCount() is helpful. Thanks.